# Is pthreads doing busy waiting internally?

Tags: c, pthreads, internals, busy-waiting

I would like to know if `pthreads` is doing **busy waiting internally** when calling `pthread_cond_timedwait()`?

I'm analysing a multi-threaded program and need to know if a thread is potentially blocking ressources when calling the above function.

Platform: Intel x86_64, CentOS 7.5.1804 with GCC 5.3.0

Comment: Short answer: "no."  (You can easily detect busy-waiting because the CPU utilization will be at or near 100% when the program isn't "doing" anything.)  If the timeout interval passes without the condition being signaled, the call will end with an appropriate error-code.  But the system is not "busy waiting" in the meantime.  The bug in your application that you're looking for lies somewhere else ...

Comment: It only blocks the calling thread

Comment: `Platform:` - what operating system? What implementation of `pthread_cond_timedwait()` are you using? [Looks like](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/nptl/pthread_cond_wait.c#L502) glibc uses futexes.

Comment: I updated the question with a more precise platform specification. I also clarified my intention. My program is always "doing something", there are more threads than execution units and I need to make sure that the calling thread is not obstructing the workers. How do I identify which implementation I use? Does futexes mean busy waiting or no busy waiting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you will have read in their documentation, the `pthread_cond_wait()` and `pthread_cond_timedwait()` functions cause the calling thread to *block* until the CV is signaled, or, in the latter case, the specified time arrives. (Or the thread is cancelled, or it is temporarily aroused to handle a signal, or ....)  Blocking does not merely mean that the thread does not return from the function. It means that the thread is not scheduled on any execution unit as long as it remains blocked.  Thus, no, threads blocked in `pthread_cond_timedwait()` do not busy-wait.